Best practice for fetching common metadata for entities in Spring Boot
I have a BaseEntity class in my Spring Boot application that includes common fields for all entities:
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String creatorId;
    private ZonedDateTime createTime;
    private String updaterId;
    private ZonedDateTime updateTime;
    private boolean deleted;
}

Each entity in the application inherits from BaseEntity. When displaying the create-update information for any entity, I need to map the creatorId and updaterId to full names from the User table.
To achieve this, I created an API for each entity that retrieves the create-update info using a repository query specific to that entity. However, this leads to duplicated logic across multiple APIs and service methods.
To avoid duplication, I tried to create a single API, getCreateUpdateInfo(), that accepts an entity ID and a type (to identify the entity). In a shared service, I used a switch statement to call the appropriate repository query based on the type.
Example of the shared service logic:
public CreateUpdateInfoDto getCreateUpdateInfo(IdTypeEnumDto dto) {
    return switch (dto.getTypeEnum()) {
        case USER -> userRepository.getCreateUpdateInfo(dto.getId());
        case ORDER -> orderRepository.getCreateUpdateInfo(dto.getId());
        case PROJECT -> projectRepository.getCreateUpdateInfo(dto.getId());
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled entity type: " + dto.getTypeEnum());
    };
}

While this reduces redundancy, I am not entirely satisfied with the switch-based design...
Is it better to keep separate endpoints for retrieving create-update metadata for each entity, or is there a more efficient way to implement a shared logic without duplication?

Have you tried creating a criteria query based the entity type determined by IdTypeEnumDto?

Now if only you could map relations between entities... What prevents you from using User updater instead of String updaterId? Mark it as a lazy relation and it will only be loaded when needed.

@SpaceTrucker I've never used it, but I'll check it out now, thank you

@M.Deinum The application is designed in such a way that we do not store entities within other entities, but rather only their IDs.

So basically you are reinventing JPA within your own application... If you want to retrieve everyting, write a query that does so. Don't do fetch 1 row, fetch another row based on an id, fetch yet another row. Unless you want an application that will criple your database and poor performance.

@M.Deinum Making use of JPA relationships in such cases may make it harder in future to split the system into different services because they allow for easier creep-in of code dependent on the user table. But especially a user table is something that will very often be separated from an application in future because of requirements for SSO and related stuff.

Ah yes the fallacy of "future proofing our architecture" ... If you start to separate things out performance will degrade further as you now probably need HTTP calls. But alas. As stated currently you apparently don't have that so write a query that retrieves the view specific data in one go, don't do 1 + whatever number of queries you need, that will only complicate things, lead to poor performance.

To implement a strategy pattern where each entity type has its own handler for retrieving create-update metadata, strategy pattern can be considered. It allows you to delegate the responsibility of fetching the data to specific strategy implementations.
Here is the solution way shown below
1 ) Define an Interface for Handlers
public interface CreateUpdateInfoHandler {
    boolean supports(IdTypeEnum type);
    CreateUpdateInfoDto getCreateUpdateInfo(Long id);
}

2 ) Implement Handlers for Each Entity
@Service
public class UserCreateUpdateInfoHandler implements CreateUpdateInfoHandler {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserCreateUpdateInfoHandler(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(IdTypeEnum type) {
        return type == IdTypeEnum.USER;
    }

    @Override
    public CreateUpdateInfoDto getCreateUpdateInfo(Long id) {
        return userRepository.getCreateUpdateInfo(id);
    }
}

@Service
public class OrderCreateUpdateInfoHandler implements CreateUpdateInfoHandler {
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

    public OrderCreateUpdateInfoHandler(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(IdTypeEnum type) {
        return type == IdTypeEnum.ORDER;
    }

    @Override
    public CreateUpdateInfoDto getCreateUpdateInfo(Long id) {
        return orderRepository.getCreateUpdateInfo(id);
    }
}

3 ) Register and Use Handlers in the Shared Service
@Service
public class CreateUpdateInfoService {
    private final List<CreateUpdateInfoHandler> handlers;

    public CreateUpdateInfoService(List<CreateUpdateInfoHandler> handlers) {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public CreateUpdateInfoDto getCreateUpdateInfo(IdTypeEnumDto dto) {
        return handlers.stream()
                .filter(handler -> handler.supports(dto.getTypeEnum()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled entity type: " + dto.getTypeEnum()))
                .getCreateUpdateInfo(dto.getId());
    }
}

4 ) Endpoints in a controller to fetch create-update info for any entity
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class MetadataController {
    private final CreateUpdateInfoService createUpdateInfoService;

    public MetadataController(CreateUpdateInfoService createUpdateInfoService) {
        this.createUpdateInfoService = createUpdateInfoService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/create-update-info")
    public ResponseEntity<CreateUpdateInfoDto> getCreateUpdateInfo(@RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam IdTypeEnum type) {
        IdTypeEnumDto dto = new IdTypeEnumDto(id, type);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createUpdateInfoService.getCreateUpdateInfo(dto));
    }
}

Here is the sample request shown below
/api/v1/create-update-info?id=123&type=USER


Thank you for the detailed answer, I implemented it, it works fine so far.
